# Published Aurelia Application Virtual Directory 404 Error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aurelia, iis-8.5

I have a .NETCORE application being an Aurelia Framework app. I also have a .NETCORE Web API. To publish these to the server I use the CMD .net publish --framework netcoreapp1.0.

I host this site on the Default Web Site which is pointing to the Aurelia app. Inside of this site I have another application being the web api. The site and API run great. I recently tried to create a Virtual Directory to server my images. Any time I try to navigate to //mywebserver/images I get nothing but 404 errors. I can play with the permissions and have it give me a 401.2 unauthorized, but any other time I just get a 404 error.

I can create a dummy website pointing to the IIS wwwroot folder, create a virtual directory and it works like it should, so I would think it has something to do with these published apps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles across this question. Shortly after posting I came across some information on a site. http://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/
Matthias discusses that with .netcore Virtual Directories are basically dead and you should start using app.UseFileServer in your startup.cs file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I seems that the '404' Http return code is the default error code in **published** .netCore apps (I had this return with a sql server connection problem).

I think it is not related to Aurelia. use `app.UseFileServer` to handle your images.